# Odoo / OpenERP x2many display create/edit only

Tags: widget, many-to-many, odoo, one-to-many

I have an editable tree within my form which is used to add certain customers to the form, each customer may have one or more addresses. Since everything else looks awful, I'm using the 'many2many_tags' widget for the addresses. 
The relevant code looks like this:

```
<field name="customer" mode="tree"...>
    <tree string="Customer" editable="bottom">
        <field name="name"/>
        <field name="addresses" widget="many2many_tags"/>
    </tree>
</field>
```

I know the 'create/edit' and 'delete' options can be disabled by adding 'edit="False" etc. to the tree tag. However, what I want to do is disable the suggestions made by the system as it is quite unlikely that the user will have to select an address which is already the system for a new customer.

Does anybody know how to do this or a least how to put the 'create/edit" option on top of the list so the user will not have to scroll all the way down through the suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, if I understand You correctly, field *customer*, is many2one to *res.partner* model, and field *addresses* is *many2many* to *res.partner* model.

I think the solution You are looking for is to use domain to filter out wrong addresses. So code may look like:

```
<field name="customer" mode="tree"
       context="{'customer': customer}">
    <tree string="Customer" editable="bottom">
        <field name="name"/>
        <field name="addresses"
               domain="[('parent_id', '=', customer)]"  
               context="{'default_parent_id', '=', customer)]"
               widget="many2many_tags"/>
    </tree>
</field>
```

This code, theoreticaly, should display only addresses of right customer, and if that customer have no addresses yet, it will no display any suggestions, but just items to create new address.